# How can I export a command that has quotes in it? Im getting an error when I try to nest single quotes within double quote

Tags: docker, ubuntu, quotes, cardano

I am attempting to add this to export in my profile

export CLI ='docker-compose exec cardano-node sh -c "CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=/ipc/node.socket cardano-cli"'

This command works with no issue from the command line
docker-compose exec cardano-node sh -c "CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=/ipc/node.socket cardano-cli"

I tried it placing it in quote a number of ways and I keep getting the following error

cardano-cli": -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
cardano-cli": -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

What's the deal here?

Answer (score 1):

[`docker-compose exec`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/) takes a `-e` option to set environment variables.  If you use that option, you don't need the `sh -c` wrapper, since you are just running a simple command, and this removes a layer of quotes.

```sh
export CLI=`docker-compose exec -e CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=/ipc/node.socket cardano-node cardano-cli`
```

`docker-compose exec` will also get the environment variables from the `docker-compose.yml` file, so if you declare the variables there

```yaml
services:
  cardano-node:
    environment:
      - CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=/ipc/node.socket
```

you don't have to repeat them in `docker-compose exec` at all

```sh
export CLI=`docker-compose exec cardano-node cardano-cli`
```

Comment: That worked, but after I made a change. I changed the quotes from ` to ".

Then it worked like a charm.

Thank you David!!